# Automatic Maintenance Mode during All in One Port

Tags: migration

I often use "All in One Migration" plugin to migrate from development to production stage. The site is about 2 GB in size.

Is there a way to automatically place the website into Maintenance mode when restore is occurring? Rather than avoid the white screen of WP death!

Comment: You're going to need knowledge of All in One Migration to do this, there won't be a generic WP way to do this, but there is a slim chance, if you run All in One Migration via CLI it might be possible ( I don't know if that plugin supports CLI ), otherwise the Q would get closed as offtopic and you'd have to contact their support, 3rd party plugins are offtopic on WPSE

Comment: Hi geekcohen, welcome to [wordpress.se]. As a rule, the community considers questions about third-party plugins (such as the one you have asked about) off-topic so you might notice some down-votes and answers may be slow if they come at all. You can find out what questions are a good fit [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).